# SSRS not using data source specified in Report Manager

Tags: visual-studio, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to create reports that are run in SSRS on MS SQL Server 2008.  I am able to successfully create reports that run on Sybase, Oracle and PostGresql databases.  Recently we added an SQL Server database that I need to create a report against.  I can create the .rdl and run it against an embedded data source that I specify in VS but when I load it to SSRS and specify a new data source in the Report Manager it will error.  The error always specifies my embedded connection as if the connection specified in the Report Manager is not overriding as expected.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After working for months with the software vendor and an internal administrator, it turns out the shared datasource was not setup correctly which I suspect won't come as a surprise to many when reviewing the scenario.